# Custom Exception Thrown by a Web Service not seen as same type by the Client (using shared assemblies)

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, exception

I have created a custom exception `InvalidSessionException`.  However when trying to catch or evaluate if the exception raised is of that type, it doesn't work.  Meaning that it both `EX is` and `Catch Ex`, don't evaluate to `InvalidSessionException`

```
try 
{
    acc = this.fda.GetAccountHeader(this.selectedTicket.AccountId);
}  
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    if (ex is Enterprise.Data.InformationModel.CustomExceptions.InvalidSessionException) 
    {
        this.lblError.Text = Resources.Resource.error_sessionedTimedOut;
        this.MPError.Show();
    }
    return;
}
```

I have also tried (without any difference in results)

```
catch (Enterprise.Data.InformationModel.CustomExceptions.InvalidSessionException ex) 
{
    this.lblError.Text = Resources.Resource.error_sessionedTimedOut;
    this.MPError.Show();
    return;
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    return;
}
```

From what I can tell the exception being thrown is of the correct type.

[image]

More Information:

`ex.GetType().FullName` = `"System.ServiceModel.FaultException1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"`

Reuse Types is enabled on the service?
[image]

Comment: The debugger seems to show that it's an `InvalidSessionException`.  What else makes you think it's not recognized as such?

Comment: it never hits the code when 'Catch' or 'Is' is evalutated

Comment: So - if you add a catch(InvalidSessionException ex) { ...} block, and stick a break point in it, it won't get hit?

Comment: correct @jay I dont hit that code/break point

Comment: Where are you throwing your `InvalidSessionException` instance?

Comment: Class full name is the same but assemblies are the same? Are you sure you aren't throwing from assembly A and catching exception from assembly B?

Comment: Is there another exception type that wrapping the `InvalidSessionException` as the `InnerException`?

Comment: Related question - is the exception thrown across system boundaries?  Meaning from a Web Service or other interop layer?

Comment: yes from a web service

Comment: we have our IM dll which defines the exception.  Then we have our framework, which pushes out the exception, another dll which sits inbetween the web service and the UI which simply throws the exception to the UI (code above)

Comment: Then actually you're not catching that exception but another one with same namespace and class name (unless you deploy original assembly to clients and you reuse types). See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15293784/1207195) for few more details.

Comment: the IM which defines {InvalidSessionException} is the "original assembly" afaik, but a little foggy on what your saying

Comment: See post linked in previous comment. Actually if you do not deploy (and reuse types from) assembly where exception is located, right? Then each client has to "build" its own copy of that type. It has same members and name but it's not that one (so if web service throws exception "Data.MyException, MyAssembly" actually you get "Data.MyException, MyAssemblyProxy". Same name, different thing. If you deploy your assemblies to ws clients then you have to ask to _reuse_ existing types.

Comment: Key paragraph from linked answer: _"It works creating a **copy of your data** and sending them from server to client, clients will then create a **new class** with the **same signature**. Note: a new class with the same signature, **not a new object** of the original class."_

Comment: What kind of web service? WCF? And did you use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: JohnSaunders = WCF, yes|  @Adriano so I understand that post and what your saying to an extent.  But Im not sure I understand how to solve the problem.  Even if the objects are stripped down to values the class is the same (shared assembly) and so I would think the {Type} would be the same.  Not to mention the exception itself looks correct when debugging and opening it up.

Comment: @owengerig I don't think it's easy to see the difference, just try to see what ex.GetType().FullName is. Are assemblies shared on clients and you **explictly** set to use them? By default it won't reuse types even if have a reference to that DLL.

Comment: SOAP web services pass XML across the wire. The client will receive an XML representation of your custom exception instance, and will deserialize it. Unless you give the client the _exact same exception class_, it will only be able to deserialize it into a class which is more or less a copy of the structure of your real class. The fact that this _proxy class_ has the same name and maybe namespace is not relevant.

Comment: right john but with what Adriano is saying and with me sharing assemblies its a different scenario AFAIK.  @Adriano what do i have to do to have them use the shared assembly.  you say "DataContractSerializer will build the right object on your clients " in the other post but then here you say i need to "explicitly set to use them".  how do i do that?  is that what your referencing when you say "write your own serializer" in the other post?

Comment: @owengerig no, custom serializer was for something completely different. In your case you just have to _ask_ VS to reuse types from a referenced assembly (it's an option when you add a service reference). Reuse types = do not create a new class with same signature (what John explained in his comment) but map them to somethiing you have. See very last sentence in that post.

Comment: ok so I think I missed understood or mis-stated something.  because this is a dll file that I add as a reference (NOT a service reference).  when adding my IM.dll I do not see any options about Reuse Types?

Comment: just to clarify.  it uses WCF for the call GetAccountHeader, the WCF service throws an exception.  The exception type is custom and defined in our Information Modal DLL (IM.DLL).  This IM.dll is shared by the WCF service and the client receiving the exception.  (shared meaning the same version of the dll is coppied and referenced by both projects)

Comment: @Adriano I added a couple things to the post.  Including a screenshot of the fact that Reuse Types is enabled?

Comment: Yes, they are reused. Still doesn't catch it? What it gives if when you catch it your dump ex.GetType().FullName?

Comment: editted into the post above but its: 'ex.GetType().FullName = "System.ServiceModel.FaultException1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Credit where credit is due**
Nintey-nine percent of the credit of this answer goes to the comment left by [Adriano Repetti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712231/custom-exception-thrown-by-a-web-service-not-seen-as-same-type-by-the-client-us#comment32831420_21712231) on this page. I just tested this solution out myself as I was having the exact same problem as described in the question above.

**The Problem**
[image: Configure Service Reference window assemblies section]
In reference to the "Configure Service Reference" modal window; just because you select “Reuse types in all referenced assemblies” does not mean that it will actually do it – it seems to be a lazy operation and basically those references will be made if the auto generation code *happens* to match it up.
**The Solution**
Therefore if you actually check mark what you care about, it seems like it is guaranteed to be used instead of *maybe*. This is accomplished by changing the radio button from “Reuse types in all referenced assemblies” to “Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies” (second radio button option).

**My Supporting Observations**
It seems like this specifically affects FaultExceptions, I don’t know why, but it does. My FaultExceptions in my project were being generated under the service reference's namespace instead of re-using them from the referenced assembly.
What is especially puzzling is that the namspace is specifically described when you look at the Reference.cs of the service reference code. Even so, it was not working until I did what I described above. Lastly I just want to point out that this is an excellent example of "breaking canon" or "not being canonical".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use strongly typed `FaultException<T>`.  Something like...

*DISCLAIMER: the following code has not been tested*

**SERVER SIDE**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISampleService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [FaultContractAttribute(typeof(InvalidSessionException)]
  void SampleMethod();
}

void SampleMethod()
{
  ...
  throw new FaultException<InvalidSessionException>();
}
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
...

try
{
   _wcfChannel.SampleMethod();

   catch (FaultException<InvalidSessionException> ex)
   {
      // take appropriate action
   }
}
```

**ADDITIONAL READING**

- MSDN: [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- remondo.net: [Using WCF Typed Fault Exceptions](http://www.remondo.net/using-wcf-typed-fault-exceptions/) (a simple example)
- iDesign: [WCF Fault Contract](http://www.idesign.net/Downloads) (sample code)
- CodeProject: [A Beginner's Tutorial for Understanding Exception Handling, FaultExceptions and FaultContracts in WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555415/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-Exception-H)

Comment: From a design perspective, I personally don't like the idea of coupling my server side code to WCF.  I would prefer to throw a *normal* exception, and then convert it to a `FaultException<T>` just before it enters the WCF communication channel. No idea how easy/hard this would be to implement.

Comment: This is the latest approach im taking but it still doesnt catch it in the proper catch statement, it always goes to the generic one, ie. catch (exception ex) rather then catch (FaultException<InvalidSessionException> ex) .

Comment: I've used the approach described above and it has worked like a charm.  Some things to consider: (1) The order in which you catch your exceptions does not matter - put more specific exceptions first. (2) Has the `FaultContractAttribute` attribute been assigned to the appropriate server side method? (3) Consider building a small demo application to test the implementation - this will eliminate "noise" and will make your problem easier to solve. (4) My memory is fuzzy... but you might have to enable custom WCF exceptions via the server side configuration - check the MSDN documentation.

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint inside the catch block and then try the following in the *Watch* window in *Visual Studio*: ex as FaultException<InvalidSessionException>