# How to return standard message on exception/fault in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception, wcf-faults

In our application all data contract have one parent - `OperationResponse` and this `OperationResponse` contains enum (enum type `OperationState` in property `Result`) which represents calling result (*Ok*, *InvalidParams*, *Error*).

How can I overwrite WCF behavior after exception - not return Fault state, but return classic message, OperationResponse in my case, but with property Result = OperationState.Error?

**Edit:** I think, I'm on right way, I need to implement IErrorHandler, but now I'm lost, because I don't know how to set error message into outgoing fault message...

```
public bool HandleError(Exception error)
{
    // log error
    return true; // we catch error and provide our custom message.
}

public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
{
    // create result message
    var message = new OperationResponse
    {
        Result = OperationState.Error
    };

    // ok how to return message into ref fault?
}
```

**Edit2:** It seems like it's unbreakable problem without solution... I only found same questions without solution like [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1865838.aspx?How%20can%20I%20handle%20the%20exceptions%20without%20returning%20a%20Fault%20message%20in%20WCF%20)... :(

Comment: look at these:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369882/wcf-web-service-custom-exception-error-to-client  ,  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650547.aspx , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331183/catching-custom-exception-from-wcf ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but it is a fairly manageable way to handle errors from WCF (and probably other systems/contexts).

Here we create a generic `ServiceResponse<T>`, which can contain any type of response in the property `Data`, and status information in `Succeeded` and `StatusMessage`.

Use the `CreateServiceResponse()` to sort of wrap which ever method you want to call inside this object. This way, you can return a `ServiceResponse` with `Data` set to the result from that method. There is an example of usage at the bottom.

Perhaps you can adjust this to return an instance of your `OperationResponse` with an `OperationState` instead of the `Succeeded` property used here?

```
public class ServiceResponse<T>
{
    public ServiceResponse()
    {
        // Initial default values:
        Data = default(T);
        Succeeded = true;
        StatusMessage = string.Empty;
    }

    // Indicates whether the attempted operation was completed successfully. 
    [DataMember]
    public bool Succeeded { get; set; }

    // Error messages if an operation fails.
    [DataMember]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    // The main results from any service-call.        
    [DataMember]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String InnerExceptionMessage { get; set; }

    public static ServiceResponse<T> CreateServiceResponse(Func<T> responseFunc)
    {
        var response = new ServiceResponse<T>();

        try
        {
            response.Data = responseFunc.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response = HandleException(responseFunc, ex);
        }

        return response;
    }

    private static ServiceResponse<T> HandleException(Func<T> responseFunc, Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions here, and return a ServiceResponse with 
        // Succeeded = false, and the appropriate messages, etc.
    }
}
```

Example of usage (assuming GetClients() will return an IEnumerable):

```
var response = ServiceResponse<IEnumerable<Client>>
                   .CreateServiceResponse(() => GetClients(clientGroupId));
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for reply, actually we developed similar approach, so I'm happy that someone use similar approach and it show me, that we are on right way... :)

Comment: Glad to be of help! It's also encouraging that you reached a similar solution. We've been using it for a while now, and it seems to be working quite well.